# How to concatenate all the occurences of the tags field inside of a list produced by the extension data-processor

Tags: data-processor

I am generating a table of contacts (name, address, e-mail, ... and tags) based upon a certain condition using the `data-processor` extension.

I want to include in that table all the tags related to the same contact, but when several tags are set, the record of this contact is repeated in the list for each tag.

I wonder if it is possible, using `data-processor`, to include one column of my table grouping all the occurences of the tag field with the concatenation function, as with the MySQL function `CONCAT_WS (separator, expression1, expression2, expression3,...)`. The separator should be the string `,`  (comma blank).

Comment: I do not think this is possible atm. Best guess is to write a custom aggregation function. You may want to have a look at the activity data source which has a configurable aggregation section.